# Error in opening UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller, uidocumentpickervc

I am trying to present UIDocumentPickerViewController from my Viewcontroller. Sometimes I get error saying **Could not communicate with a helper application.**

The way I present my DocumentPickerViewController is:

```
BHFilePickerViewController *documentPicker = [[BHFilePickerViewController alloc]initWithDocumentTypes:types inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
documentPicker.filePickerDelegate = self;
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:true completion:nil];
```

Where, BHFilePickerViewController is my custom class of type **UIDocumentPickerViewController**.

When issue occurs I can see the log as

```
[DocumentManager] The view service did terminate with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted} 
Remote view controller crashed with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}. Trying to relaunch.
[u 571773A2-04B9-4EAB-A4AE-E0C629CB07AF:m (null)] [com.apple.DocumentManagerUICore.Service(1.0)] Connection to plugin interrupted while in use.
[DocumentManager] Failed to get the remote browser View Controller with error (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.DocumentManagerUICore.Service.viewservice was interrupted, but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this proxy has become invalid." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.DocumentManagerUICore.Service.viewservice was interrupted, but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this proxy has become invalid.})
[DocumentManager] Remote view controller crashed with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.DocumentManagerUICore.Service.viewservice was interrupted, but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this proxy has become invalid." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.DocumentManagerUICore.Service.viewservice was interrupted, but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this proxy has become invalid.}. Trying to relaunch.
```

Am I presenting it wrong way? What could you be improved?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have this key in Info.plist UISupportsDocumentBrowser?

Comment: Yes, I have that key added in my plist.